# NextJS TypeScript API Route 404 Error (Not Found)

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm currently working on a full stack application that is using NextJS, Prisma, and PostgreSQL. I need to obviously make requests to the database to CRUD data. I'm using NextJS's API routes as my way to call on Prisma from server-side to make changes to the PostgreSQL database, since I can't really use Prisma in the client-side environment of NextJS/React.

However, I'm getting errors with my API routes. I'm using Insomnia to send API requests and keep getting 404, 405, or any other error. I have looked at many solutions online, tried redoing my directories and files, but nothing has worked.

This is my directory `pages/api` as instructed on the [NextJS documentation](https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/basics/api-routes/creating-api-routes):
[Screenshot of entire application's directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0CLk.png)

Additionally, this is an example of my `pages/api/route.ts` file:
[Screenshot of an API route file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suUGO.png)

This is the error I get from Insomnia when making a request to the API:
[Screenshot of 404 error from API request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHXS8.png)

I've tried looking at other StackOverflow solutions, GitHub solutions, or any other place on the internet with a similar problem but nothing worked. Even tried remaking the directory setup and redoing the tutorial in the NextJS documentation but nothing still works.

Comment: hey! shouldn't the call be made to the `http://localhost:3000/api/route` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

you are making the API request to the incorrect URL. In your case, it should be something like

> http://localhost:3000/api/route

The error suggests a 404, which means the endpoint is not found.

Comment: Tried this in Insomnia. Still getting a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the `pages` router inside the `app` router? They are different conventions. So, inside the app router use the `api/jobs/route.ts` handler, and follow the app router convention to create a router handler. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#convention

Comment: Tried this but I get the 405 "Method Not Allowed" error.

Comment: When you get this 405 status code, you are defining a request method and sending another request method. For example, In the route `api/jobs` handler, you defined a GET method and you're sending a POST request with the route or vice-versa.